# gnome-shell crashing + can't send report

Tags: gnome-shell

In last time happens that while not doing any heavy workload PC just freezes and I need to shut it down bu holding Power button. Now in /var/crash there is gnome-shell.crash file which is from about when problem occurred and I get "report problem" pop up when I boot into Ubuntu but after pressing button it doesn't bring up additional dialog to report problem, is there a way to report bug manually since I don't how to do that I'd say launchpad is a bit complicated.

Anyway how can I determine crash cause myself if that is possible for average user to do so? I think, but I'm not 100% sure that crashes occurres only after when laptop was in sleep.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.03 on i5 2520m

Output of the ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
https://pastebin.com/iA1jknmS

I had looked into grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog* it throws a ton of lines and some extensions are mentioned as warnings.

Comment: Rather than power off using power-key, I would suggest using the [magic] SysRq keys to shutdown (REISUB). I included the word magic as it'll cause the wikipedia to appear at top of list which can be a great reminder (https://ubuntu.com/blog/prepare-for-when-ubuntu-freezes)  If you go to terminal you can type `ubuntu-bug /var/crash/<report.name>.cash`  (on rare occasion it'll require `sudo` as well) and it will submit.  The file is ascii so you can view it, though I doubt the average user would understand much.

Comment: You've probably got a bad GNOME Shell extension. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and if you look at `grep -i gnome-shell /var/log/syslog*` you can probably find the name of the bad extension. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema updated

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for this I will try it out.

Comment: To see if a GNOME extension is causing your problem... temporarily disable ALL GNOME extensions, and see if the problem goes away. If it does, re-enable ONE extension at a time until the problem returns. `Dash to Dock` has some known problems in 19.04... but it used to be ok in 18.xx... maybe that's changed.

Comment: Good call I will do that and report back.